# Filter objects in array by value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have, what I believe to be, an array of objects:

```
[{"Id":1,"productId":122,"product_quantity":1}, {"Id":1,"productId":133,"product_quantity":2},{"Id":2,"productId":144,"product_quantity":1}]
```

I am using this code to get all the values:

```
$.each(JSON.parse(myArray), function(key, value){ // stuff }
```

I am trying to filter on Id and return the results associated with it.  I have tried nesting .each and using `if(value.id = myVariableID)` but nothing seems to work.
I would like to return `(where Id = 1)`:

```
id : 1 | productID : 122 | product_quantity: 1, id : 1 | productID : 133 | procuct_quantity: 2
```

as an example.

Comment: Also [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](//stackoverflow.com/q/237104)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why just don't use Array's `filter()`:

```js
var myArray = [{"Id":1,"productId":122,"product_quantity":1}, {"Id":1,"productId":133,"product_quantity":2},{"Id":2,"productId":144,"product_quantity":1}];

var res = myArray.filter(i => i.Id == 1);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: when using .filter, I get `.filter is not a function`.

Comment: @user2796515, please follow my code snippet, how I have used filter on the array to get the desired output....thanks.

Comment: that does work, but when I insert my actual array as the myVariable.filter it doesn't work.  Must be something else I am doing wrong - I have clicked yours as a correct answer and will keep working on it.  Thank you.

Comment: @user2796515, you are most welcome and best of luck.